# jar packages added to list tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip= but stacktrace doesn't change and server doesn't start

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server, jar

I was told to use server 9.0.69.
jar packages added to list tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip= but stacktrace doesn't change and server doesn't start.
I followed the instructions given to me in the previous question, I also set the bounty and my server won't start. I tried using the suggestions from questions similar to mine, but they didn't help. Can anyone help me please? Thank you

the strange thing is that in the lib folder I have 34 jar packages, while in the server stacktrace it tells me to add the jars of the lib folder of the wokspace/.metadata/plugin/org.eclipse.wst.server.core./tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib folder to the list ( 56 jars).Then there is also the tmp0 folder perhaps because I changed server.

[java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74575870/java-lang-classcastexception-class-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherse)

stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-3.0.0.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.916 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.13.4.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.918 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.920 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-42.3.8.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.922 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/classmate-1.5.1.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.930 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.4.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.931 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.el-5.0.0-M1.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.934 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.939 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.941 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.942 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/txw2-2.3.7.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.943 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/maven-deploy-plugin-3.0.0.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.945 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.947 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.13.4.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.949 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.953 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/maven-compiler-plugin-3.10.1.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:13.955 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.servlet-api-5.0.0-M2.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.142 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan TLD files were found in JAR [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-2.0.0-M1.jar].
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.144 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.192 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan TLD files were found in JAR [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/taglibs-standard-jstlel-1.2.5.jar].
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.198 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/byte-buddy-1.12.19.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.200 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.202 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-5.3.23.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.203 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/checker-qual-3.5.0.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.205 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.207 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.218 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/maven-clean-plugin-3.2.0-sources.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.263 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan TLD files were found in JAR [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/taglibs-standard-compat-1.2.5.jar].
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.264 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.inject-api-2.0.0.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.266 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.websocket-api-2.1.0.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.272 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-2.7.4.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.276 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-6.0.0.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.280 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/maven-resources-plugin-3.3.0.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.284 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/maven-surefire-plugin-3.0.0-M7.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.287 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-5.3.23.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.389 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan TLD files were found in JAR [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5%20(1).jar].
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.393 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/maven-war-plugin-3.3.2.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.518 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan TLD files were found in JAR [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-2.0.0%20(1).jar].
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.520 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/maven-install-plugin-3.0.1.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.620 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan TLD files were found in JAR [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.1.jar].
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.625 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-5.3.23.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.631 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.677 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan TLD files were found in JAR [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar].
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.690 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-annotations-api-9.0.69.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.695 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/lombok-1.18.22.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.700 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.3.23.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.704 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.13.4.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.709 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.713 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Users/segreteria/Desktop/WORKSPACE%204/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Parlamento/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.721 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0_Tomcat9.0.69/lib/jakartaee-migration-1.0.1-shaded.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.839 FINE [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan TLD files were found in JAR [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0_Tomcat9.0.69/lib/jstl-1.2.jar].
09-Dec-2022 12:05:14.845 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

catalina.properties

```
    tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=
annotations-api.jar,
ant-junit*.jar,
ant-launcher.jar,
ant.jar,
asm-*.jar,
aspectj*.jar,
bootstrap.jar,
catalina-ant.jar,
catalina-ha.jar,
catalina-ssi.jar,
catalina-storeconfig.jar,
catalina-tribes.jar,
catalina.jar,
cglib-*.jar,
cobertura-*.jar,
commons-beanutils*.jar,
commons-codec*.jar,
commons-collections*.jar,
commons-daemon.jar,
commons-dbcp*.jar,
commons-digester*.jar,
commons-fileupload*.jar,
commons-httpclient*.jar,
commons-io*.jar,
commons-lang*.jar,
commons-logging*.jar,
commons-math*.jar,
commons-pool*.jar,
derby-*.jar,
dom4j-*.jar,
easymock-*.jar,
ecj-*.jar,
el-api.jar,
geronimo-spec-jaxrpc*.jar,
h2*.jar,
ha-api-*.jar,
hamcrest-*.jar,
hibernate*.jar,
httpclient*.jar,
icu4j-*.jar,
jasper-el.jar,
jasper.jar,
jaspic-api.jar,
jaxb-*.jar,
jaxen-*.jar,
jaxws-rt-*.jar,
jdom-*.jar,
jetty-*.jar,
jmx-tools.jar,
jmx.jar,
jsp-api.jar,
jstl.jar,
jta*.jar,
junit-*.jar,
junit.jar,
log4j*.jar,
mail*.jar,
objenesis-*.jar,
oraclepki.jar,
oro-*.jar,
servlet-api-*.jar,
servlet-api.jar,
slf4j*.jar,
taglibs-standard-spec-*.jar,
tagsoup-*.jar,
tomcat-api.jar,
tomcat-coyote.jar,
tomcat-dbcp.jar,
tomcat-i18n-*.jar,
tomcat-jdbc.jar,
tomcat-jni.jar,
tomcat-juli-adapters.jar,
tomcat-juli.jar,
tomcat-util-scan.jar,
tomcat-util.jar,
tomcat-websocket.jar,
tools.jar,
websocket-api.jar,
wsdl4j*.jar,
xercesImpl.jar,
xml-apis.jar,
xmlParserAPIs-*.jar,
xmlParserAPIs.jar,
xom-*.jar, 
jakartaee-migration-1.0.1-shaded.jar, 
jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar, 
jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar, 
jackson-annotations-2.13.4.jar, 
spring-web-5.3.23.jar, 
lombok-1.18.22.jar, 
tomcat-annotations-api-9.0.69.jar, 
spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar, 
jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar, 
spring-core-5.3.23.jar, 
taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.1.jar, 
maven-install-plugin-3.0.1.jar, 
jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-2.0.0 (1).jar, 
maven-war-plugin-3.3.2.jar, 
taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5(1).jar, 
spring-beans-5.3.23.jar, 
maven-surefire-plugin-3.0.0-M7.jar, 
maven-resources-plugin-3.3.0.jar, 
spring-core-6.0.0.jar, 
maven-resources-plugin-3.3.0.jar, 
spring-core-6.0.0.jar, 
spring-boot-2.7.4.jar, 
jakarta.websocket-api-2.1.0.jar, 
jakarta.inject-api-2.0.0.jar, 
taglibs-standard-compat-1.2.5.jar, 
maven-clean-plugin-3.2.0-sources.jar, 
jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar, 
spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar, 
checker-qual-3.5.0.jar, 
spring-context-5.3.23.jar, 
jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar, 
byte-buddy-1.12.19.jar, 
taglibs-standard-jstlel-1.2.5.jar, 
jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-2.0.0-M1.jar, 
jakarta.servlet-api-5.0.0-M2.jar, 
maven-compiler-plugin-3.10.1.jar, 
istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar, 
jackson-core-2.13.4.jar, 
jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar, 
maven-deploy-plugin-3.0.0.jar, 
jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar, 
jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar, 
spring-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar, 
jakarta.el-5.0.0-M1.jar, 
spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.4.jar, 
classmate-1.5.1.jar, 
jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-3.0.0.jar, 
antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar, 
txw2-2.3.7.jar, 
jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar, 
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.13.4.jar
```

logging.properties

```
    handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINEST
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINEST
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINEST
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINEST
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.encoding = UTF-8


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = FINEST
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = FINEST
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = FINEST
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE

# To see debug messages in TldLocationsCache, uncomment the following line:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE

# To see debug messages for HTTP/2 handling, uncomment the following line:
org.apache.coyote.http2.level = FINE

# To see debug messages for WebSocket handling, uncomment the following line:
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.level = FINE

org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.level = SEVERE

org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE
org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.level = FINE

org.apache.jasper.level = FINEST
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the list all on one line?

Comment: i tried but the error remained

Comment: I tried to remove from the list the jars whose stacktrace says "TLD files were found in Jar" so it doesn't say to consider adding them to the list of jars to skip